# "a bytes-like object is required", but type(var) returns <class 'bytes'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have to do some text processing and was having problems regarding encoding:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

So I did:

```
text = text.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

However later in the code I have to do:

```
text = text.replace(' ', '_')
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

But the type of `text` at this point *is* bytes. I ran it on the python shell and as you can see below, after the `encode` command, the result is an object of class `bytes`.

[image]

What exactly is happening here and how can I solve this? I'm working with Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you using to replace it must be a bytes-like object.

Therefore, you should use the byte representation of the characters you are wanting to replace. (try this below)

```
text = text.replace(b' ', b'_')
```

However, please know that this is fixed in python 3.6 so you should probably, if at all possible, update to this version.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fixed in python 3.6"; `text.replace(' ', '_')` raises the same type error in 3.6.5.

Comment: When I was running it on mac with version 3.6.3 it worked for me. @chepner could you please give me the example string you used?